# How can I set the icon of jlabel as background image using a jbutton?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe, jlabel

I'm using `Jframe` form for this program and here's the button code I've tried. When I ran the program and clicked the button nothing happens. Pls help.

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    ImageIcon icondir = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Awesome\\Desktop\\myaJbQq.jpg");
    ID_Background.setIcon(icondir);
}
```

Comment: Where is a runnable example?

Comment: It's just a plain Jframe sir with a jlabel and a button. The frame shows up but when the button is clicked the image didn't appear.

Comment: Only if I see the whole code and can run it on my computer I (probably) can say what's wrong.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example).

Answer (score 1):

This file (image) `C:\\Users\\Awesome\\Desktop\\myaJbQq.jpg` does not exists.

The *problem* with `ImageIcon` is that is not throwing any exception if the file/resource is missing.
Try to load the icon this way:

```
ImageIcon icondir = new ImageIcon(
    ImageIO.read(
        new File("C:\\Users\\Awesome\\Desktop\\myaJbQq.jpg")));
```

You will have for sure an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1301)
    ...
```

Comment: Can you see what is wrong on his computer? Are you  clairvoyant?

Comment: Sir it's in my desktop and I'm correct with its filename.

Comment: i updated the answer, try with my example and see if is working

Comment: Sorry sir but nothing happens. I guess this has something to do with the Jlabel properties?

Comment: Maybe you are not updating the icon to the proper label? :) (this is why alwsys is better to post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))

Comment: Sir I'm sure about everything on what I've posted. Its clear with the label name sir.

Answer (score 0):

```
ID_Background.repaint();
```

Should fix your issue. If not, I'm going to need more code than what you've provided (what the ID_Background is, how your GUI is setup, etc).